# Symfony 1.4 - How to use backend-filters in table_method?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, filtering

I'd like to use a custom filter in my table_method to extend a query. Unfortunately I do not know how to access the field's value from within the method. I'm using SF 1.4 /w Doctrine 1.2

Comment: If you mean adding a custom field to a filter form you should read e.g. [this](http://botchedcode.com/2010/02/11/symfony-1-4-adding-custom-filter/).

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I did. But the filter isn't applied to the list automatically. So I'd like to modify the list-query using the value from the custom filter field. I don't know how to access this value from within the table_method.

Comment: You can set up default values of fields in the filter form class or  use the `getFilterDefaults()` function in the generator configuration class to set up default values for the filter form (return an array like `array('field_name' => 'default_value')`). The filters will be automatically applied on the base query in the `buildQuery()` method of the action class. You might need to clear the session to this take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must to change the doBuildQuery filterForm method.

In any filterForm class you can do:

```
public doBuildQuery(array $values) {
    $q = parent::doBuildQuery($values);

    if($values['....']) ... {
       $q->addWhere($q->getRootAlias().".column = ?",$values['...']);
    }

    return $q; 
}
```

This method it's the one automatically called from backend generated modules. If you want to add another widget, do it in configure() method, then process the value in the doBuildQuery().